# styling label in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'd like to make part of the label in a span i.e. the * needs to be a different colour, but I'm not sure how to get the coding of this right

```
.form_field_wrapper
      = f.label :category_id, '*Category', class: 'category_label_sup_form'
      = f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, include_blank: false)
```

I've tried to do:

```
%span.green_required *
.form_field_wrapper
    = f.label :category_id, '*Category', class: 'category_label_sup_form'
    = f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, include_blank: false)
```

But that just puts the * on a line of its own

I guess the alternative is to work out why it isn't starred automatically from the model

```
validates :name, presence: true
validates :category_id, presence: true, numericality: true
```

From the validation above, the name category is automatically starred, but the category one isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the HTML which simple_form produces, then write your own CSS markup to style the elements as you need.

There is no need to modify the label within the HTML just to set the colour of the asterisk.

Comment: Like I said ... inspect the HTML. You'll see that the asterisk is wrapped in an `<abbr>` element. Just style that.

Comment: I have inspected the html but can't see any <abbr> wrapping to separate the * from 'category'

Comment: Can you provide the output HTML that you're trying to work with? It'll help to see what you're actually getting.